# Doctrine2: What is wrong with the association between these entities?

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm

I am trying to work through simple examples to see all the changes in Doctrine2.

Please take a look at the following entity snippets:

VCat.php

```
namespace Application\Models;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="v_cat")
 */
class VCat
{
    /** 
     * @Id @Column(type="bigint")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="VScat", mappedBy="vCat")     )
     */
    private $vScats;

namespace Application\Models;
```

VScat.php

```
namespace Application\Models;
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="v_scat",indexes={@index(name="FK_v_scat",columns={"vcatid"})})
 */
class VScat
{
    /** 
     * @Id @Column(type="bigint")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="VCat", inversedBy="vScats")
     * @JoinColumn(name="vcatid", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $vCat;
```

`vcatid` is the Foreign Key column in table v_scat

This is the query I am trying to run:

```
$categories = Zend_Registry::get('em')
        -> createQuery('select c.name, sub.name as sub_name from \Application\Models\VCat c JOIN c.VScat sub WHERE sub.active = 1 and c.active = 1 and c.id = sub.vcatid')
        -> getResult();
```

And this is the error:

```
(string:130) [Semantical Error] line 0, col 69 near 'sub WHERE sub.active': Error: Class Application\Models\VCat has no association named VScat
```

It seems right, but I am obviously missing something.

**UPDATE** Now I get this error, which refers to the table column name in mysql. Is that incorrect? I thought I needed to tell Doctrine somehow that this property belongs to this field in the DB.

```
 Error: Class Application\Models\VScat has no field or association named vcatid
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the property on VCat you need to reference not the entity type.

```
JOIN c.VScat sub
```

should be:

```
JOIN c.vScats sub
```

Comment: Nice. Thank you. So many changes, I was used to the model/entity reference. I updated my question though at the bottom as far as properties & DB column names. I am going to try and find a section in the docs that covers this in detail. I also just checked out the sandbox, I will take a peek in there.

Comment: @Hallik - regarding your **UPDATE**: you don't need the last part of the query `and c.id = sub.vcatid` The JOIN does this implicitly.