# How do i solve Semantical error: "Class has no association named.."

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

i am following part 5 of the symblog symfony2 tutorial:

```
http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/customising-the-view-more-with-twig.html
```

under heading: The Homepage - Blogs and Comments

when i get to update:

```
// src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Repository/BlogRepositoy.php

public function getLatestBlogs($limit = null)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
           ->select('b, c')
           ->leftJoin('b.comments', 'c')
           ->addOrderBy('b.created', 'DESC');

    if (false === is_null($limit))
    $qb->setMaxResults($limit);

    return $qb->getQuery()
          ->getResult();
}
```

and also when i update:

```
{# src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Resources/views/Page/index.html.twig #}

{# .. #}

<footer class="meta">
    <p>Comments: <a href="{{ path('BloggerBlogBundle_blog_show', { 'id': blog.id }) }}#comments">{{ blog.comments|length }}</a></p>
    <p>Posted by <span class="highlight">{{ blog.author }}</span> at {{ blog.created|date('h:iA') }}</p>
    <p>Tags: <span class="highlight">{{ blog.tags }}</span></p>
</footer>

{# .. #}
```

i then refresh my browser and get error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 71 near 'c ORDER BY b.created': Error: Class   
Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Blog has no association named comments
500 Internal Server Error - QueryException


<?php
 // src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Entity/Blog.php

 namespace Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity;

 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
 use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Blogger\BlogBundle\Repository\BlogRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="blog")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Blog
{
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->getTitle();
}

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $title;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 */
protected $author;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
protected $blog;

 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length="20")
 */
protected $image;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
protected $tags;

protected $comments;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
protected $created;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
protected $updated;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->comments = new ArrayCollection();

    $this->setCreated(new \DateTime());
    $this->setUpdated(new \DateTime());
}

public function setUpdatedValue()
{
   $this->setUpdated(new \DateTime());
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set title
 *
 * @param string $title
 */
public function setTitle($title)
{
    $this->title = $title;
}

/**
 * Get title
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->title;
}

/**
 * Set author
 *
 * @param string $author
 */
public function setAuthor($author)
{
    $this->author = $author;
}

 /**
 * Get author
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getAuthor()
{
    return $this->author;
}

/**
 * Set blog
 *
 * @param text $blog
 */
public function setBlog($blog)
{
    $this->blog = $blog;
}

/**
 * Get blog
 *
 * @return text 
 */
public function getBlog($length = null)
{
    if (false === is_null($length) && $length > 0)
       return substr($this->blog, 0, $length);
    else
       return $this->blog;
}

/**
 * Set image
 *
 * @param string $image
 */
public function setImage($image)
{
    $this->image = $image;
}

/**
 * Get image
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getImage()
{
    return $this->image;
}

/**
 * Set tags
 *
 * @param text $tags
 */
public function setTags($tags)
{
    $this->tags = $tags;
}

/**
 * Get tags
 *
 * @return text 
 */
public function getTags()
{
    return $this->tags;
}

/**
 * Set created
 *
 * @param datetime $created
 */
public function setCreated($created)
{
    $this->created = $created;
}

/**
 * Get created
 *
 * @return datetime 
 */
public function getCreated()
{
    return $this->created;
}

/**
 * Set updated
 *
 * @param datetime $updated
 */
public function setUpdated($updated)
{
    $this->updated = $updated;
}

/**
 * Get updated
 *
 * @return datetime 
 */
public function getUpdated()
{
    return $this->updated;
}
}
```

please help solve this. i dont know where i went wrong

thanks

Comment: can you post contents of Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Blog?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't paste the src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Entity/Blog.php file. It would help resolving your issue.

Most probably you didn't add comments field to your entity (or didn't annotate it properly).

Similar problem: [Doctrine2: What is wrong with the association between these entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568394/doctrine2-what-is-wrong-with-the-association-between-these-entities)

EDIT: Now when you pasted your entity I can see the comments field is not annotated. Doctrine's entity manager doesn't know anything about it. You have to provide mapping (in your case via annotations).

EDIT 2:

In your entity you should have (src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Entity/Blog.php):

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="blog")
 */
protected $comments;
```

but you have:

```
protected $comments;
```

Mapping is missing. Doctrine doesn't know how to use your field.

Comment: yikes did i miss something in that tutorial? im sure i followed it to the T? how do i add mapping via annotations? where in the tutorial is that please? Part 4 i would imagine?

Comment: i see now part 4 it says: Update the Blog entity located at src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Entity/Blog.php to add this mapping. The line i have to add into the code is:  $this->comments = new ArrayCollection(); which i have in my Blog.php

Comment: i had problem with php bin/vendors install in part 4:  [ErrorException]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  Warning: rename(/home/helloises/symfony2/Symfony/app/cache/dev,/home/helloises/symfony2/Symfony/app/cache/dev_old): Directory not empty in /home/helloises/symfony2/Symfony/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/CacheClearCommand.php line 68  
please help?

Comment: thank you! i added the /**...**/ part..error i am getting now when i refresh the browser is:  Method "comments" for object "Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Blog" does not exist in BloggerBlogBundle:Page:index.html.twig at line 19 and ofcourse the above install vendors issue :)

Answer (score 1):

I have also followed the symblog tutorial. My blog.php file is as follows:

```
<?php

namespace Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
* Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Blog
*/
class Blog
{
    /**
    * @var integer $id
    */
    private $id;


    /**
    * Get id
    *
    * @return integer 
    */
  public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}
/**
 * @var string $title
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @var string $author
 */
private $author;

/**
 * @var string $blog
 */
private $blog;

/**
 * @var string $image
 */
private $image;

/**
 * @var string $tags
 */
private $tags;

/**
 * @var string $comment
 */
private $comment;

/**
 * @var datetime $created
 */
private $created;

/**
 * @var datetime $updated
 */
private $updated;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->comments = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->setCreated(new \DateTime());
    $this->setUpdated(new \DateTime());
}
/**
 * Set title
 *
 * @param string $title
 */
public function setTitle($title)
{
    $this->title = $title;
    $this->setSlug($this->title);
}

/**
 * Get title
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->title;
}

/**
 * Set author
 *
 * @param string $author
 */
public function setAuthor($author)
{
    $this->author = $author;
}

/**
 * Get author
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getAuthor()
{
    return $this->author;
}

/**
 * Set blog
 *
 * @param string $blog
 */
public function setBlog($blog)
{
    $this->blog = $blog;
}

/**
 * Get blog
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getBlog($length = null)
{
    if (false === is_null($length) && $length > 0)
        return substr($this->blog, 0, $length);
    else
        return $this->blog;
}

/**
 * Set image
 *
 * @param string $image
 */
public function setImage($image)
{
    $this->image = $image;
}

/**
 * Get image
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getImage()
{
    return $this->image;
}

/**
 * Set tags
 *
 * @param string $tags
 */
public function setTags($tags)
{
    $this->tags = $tags;
}

/**
 * Get tags
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getTags()
{
    return $this->tags;
}

/**
 * Set comment
 *
 * @param string $comment
 */
public function setComment($comment)
{
    $this->comment = $comment;
}

/**
 * Get comment
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getComment()
{
    return $this->comment;
}

/**
 * Set created
 *
 * @param datetime $created
 */
public function setCreated($created)
{
    $this->created = $created;
}

/**
 * Get created
 *
 * @return datetime 
 */
public function getCreated()
{
    return $this->created;
}

/**
 * Set updated
 *
 * @param datetime $updated
 */
public function setUpdated($updated)
{
    $this->updated = $updated;
}

/**
 * Get updated
 *
 * @return datetime 
 */
public function getUpdated()
{
    return $this->updated;
}

public function addComment(Comment $comment)
{
    $this->comments[] = $comment;
}

public function getComments()
{
    return $this->comments;
}

/**
 * @ORM\preUpdate
 */
public function setUpdatedValue()
{
     $this->setUpdated(new \DateTime());
}

/**
 * @var Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Comment
 */
private $comments;

public function __toString()
{
    return $this->getTitle();
}

/**
 * @var string $slug
 */
protected $slug;


/**
 * Set slug
 *
 * @param string $slug
 */
public function setSlug($slug)
{
    $this->slug = $this->slugify($slug);
}

/**
 * Get slug
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getSlug()
{
    return $this->slug;
}

public function slugify($text)
{
    $text = preg_replace('#[^\\pL\d]+#u', '-', $text);

    $text = trim($text, '-');

    if (function_exists('iconv'))
    {
        $text = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);
    }

    $text = strtolower($text);

    $text = preg_replace('#[^-\w]+#', '', $text);

    if (empty($text))
    {
        return 'n-a';
    }

    return $text;
  } }
```

Hope this helps you.

Your code is missing

```
/**
* @var Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Comment
*/
private $comments;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have faced the same problem.

If you know your relationships and everything is fine.

My Solution:

```
Cache clear :)
```