# Sulu: custom data provider, enableTypes() parameters

Tags: sulu

I'm following official sulu documentation about creating custom data provider:

https://docs.sulu.io/en/2.2/cookbook/smart-content-data-provider.html#dataprovider

Here, inside ExampleDataProvider class, inside getConfiguration() method there is chunk of code:

```
        ->enableTypes([
            ['type' => 'example-type-1', 'title' => 'type-translation-key-1'],
            ['type' => 'example-type-2', 'title' => 'type-translation-key-2'],
        ])
```

And I for my repository class I'm using DataProviderRepositoryTrait trait, as suggested there.

What are those types? Can they be excluded. I assume they have something to do with filters of smart field type, but I don't understand how this works.

**Update:**

What the actual problem is - when I try to open edit page at back-end, where my smart type appears I get the error:

***[Semantical Error] line 0, col 84 near 'type WHERE entity.id': Error: Class App\Entity\MatchEvent has no association named type***

I tried just excluding the code that is adding enabled types, but it's the same.

By error, I would say that some sql query is still looking for some type parameters even I excluded enabled types, but I don't know where and how to fix this.

I found some similar issue here: [How do i solve Semantical error: "Class has no association named.."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983323/how-do-i-solve-semantical-error-class-has-no-association-named)

So if the problem is the same it means that field "type" should be added to my custom entity type. But it's not mentioned in this tutorial article?

I figured out that:

```
    public function appendJoins(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, $alias, $locale)
    {
      $queryBuilder->addSelect('type')->leftJoin($alias . '.type', 'type');
    }
```

which I had to add inside my repository class when implementing DataProviderRepositoryInterface interface is adding this 'type' to query. If I comment out that line I don't get error any more, but my field never finish loading (spinner is running infinitely)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right, this is for the filtering by `types`.  These types are e.g. the `template-keys` for `pages` and the `title` is for the translation in the admin ui.

The selected types can be used in your CustomDataProvider with the `Sulu/Component/Content/SmartContent/QueryBuilder` to filter the items by a specific type.

The `DataProviderRepositoryTrait` uses the type-filtering on the [these](https://github.com/sulu/sulu/blob/2.x/src/Sulu/Component/SmartContent/Orm/DataProviderRepositoryTrait.php#L137-L149) lines. You can also overwrite the `appendTypeRelation` method, if the alias is not correct for your custom entity.

But if you don't need filtering by types, you can just ignore it.

Comment: Thank you. I've updated my question. Can you maybe figure out why I'm getting the error I mentioned above?

Comment: In the mentioned `appendJoins` method you have to add the selects/joins which you need for your entity. The `type` select is just an example. It depends completely on your custom entity, which fields you need to select here. Furthermore it depends on which fields you need in your resulting "smart-content-item"

At the end, the `DataProviderRepository` just creates an sql-query, to load and filter/sort your custom entity.

Have a look at the [MediaDataProviderRepository](https://github.com/sulu/sulu/blob/2.x/src/Sulu/Bundle/MediaBundle/Entity/MediaDataProviderRepository.php#L115)

Comment: Great, thank you. It would be helpful to have have comments like this explaining the code at article/tutorial it self. Would save much time to others. Some things obvious to Sulu developers are maybe not so obvious to other people.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Thank you for the feedback, we will try to update our documentation.  We also always really appreciate pull requests to our [documentation repository](https://github.com/sulu/sulu-docs). :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. Thing is (if I figured it out well) that I have to either add field "type" to my custom entity (not mentioned in tutorial) or I have to comment out that one line in `appendJoins()` method so that field won't be added to sql query and cause the error.

Beside that I had some other issue, which caused my code not working even when that line is commented, but that's not relevant to this issue.